# Map key of float type

Tags: go

I have a struct type like this:

```golang
type Vertex struct {
    X, Y, Z float32
}
```

I intend to create a map with key of `Vertex` type:

```golang
var vertices map[Vertex]struct{}
```

The problem is `Go` would try to compare float32 with `==` and `!=` which are *not* suitable for float32. Instead, I prefer an approximate comparison with an `epsilon`.

I have studied [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29663169/3405291), but I don't know how to implement it, since my key `struct` has 3 fields. Can anybody help me use my struct as map key? Thanks.

Comment: Note that approximate comparison is not transitive and cannot really be used in a map. All your keys are equal, if you compare them in close enough intervals.

Comment: Find another way to generate key float approximation produces different results based on operations performed, 0.1 may be 2 different values based on how you got it; a non recommended way will be to explicitly just store the float values up-to n decimal places in a string  and use that maybe if it works.

Comment: If the builtin == is not suitable for your purpose you cannot use a Go `map`. It is really that simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Idea

Inspired by @ShubhamSrivastava comment, the idea is:

- `float32` coordinates would be rounded to a specific decimal point

#### Rationale

Since exact `==` and `!=` comparisons (required by map key) are NOT proper for float, such comparisons make more sense when `float32` is rounded consistently to a limited decimal point.

#### Implementation

I round my float32 fields inside `Vertex` type by these methods to a **specific decimal point**:

```golang
// round floating point fields of my type to a specific decimal point
func vertRoundTo(vi Vertex, decimals uint32) (vo Vertex, err error) {
    if vo.X, err = roundTo(vi.X, decimals); err != nil {
        return Vertex{}, err
    }
    if vo.Y, err = roundTo(vi.Y, decimals); err != nil {
        return Vertex{}, err
    }
    if vo.Z, err = roundTo(vi.Z, decimals); err != nil {
        return Vertex{}, err
    }
    return
}

// round float32 to a specific decimal point
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/52048478/3405291
func roundTo(fi float32, decimals uint32) (fo float32, err error) {
    if decimals < 1 {
        err = errors.New("minimum decimal point is exceeded")
        return
    }
    fo = float32(math.Round(float64(fi)*float64(decimals)) / float64(decimals))
    return
}
```

I use the above methods like this:

```golang
// "cluster" is already filled with rounded floats
func (c *cluster) DoesClusterContainVertex(v Vertex) (does bool, err error) {
    // coordinates would be rounded to a specific decimal point
    // since exact == and != comparison is NOT proper for float
    // such comparisons are required for map key
    var vRound Vertex
    if vRound, err = vertRoundTo(v, 4); err != nil {
        return
    }
    if _, ok := c.verts[vRound]; ok {
        // cluster contains vertex
        does = true
    }
    return
}
```